# How to check current window size in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

For instance, the size of the window changed (user resized it), how to get current window size?

Comment: *"how to get current window size?"* Why do you think you need it?  I've written 100s of GUIs and rarely needed to get the size of the parent container (especially not on resize).

Comment: How you handle resizing of frame then?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Rectangle r = frame.getBounds();
h = r.height;
w = r.width;
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a JFrame in which you are drawing your interface:

```
Dimension size = frame.getBounds().getSize()
```

Returns the dimensions of the frame. Additionally, you can give the frame a resize handler to catch whenever the user adjusts the frame's size:

```
    class ResizeListener implements ComponentListener {

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            Dimension newSize = e.getComponent().getBounds().getSize();          
        }   
    }

    frame.addComponentListener(new ResizeListener());
```

Comment: if you don't override most of the methods, I'd consider using [ComponentAdaper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html) instead

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `getSize()`method: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize())

Comment: I'm getting 404 on that link. Please update it and complement your answer, so this doesn't invalidate it in the future. `getSize()` method from which class?

Comment: @VictorMoraes since OP was afk for a while, I have updated broken link.