# How to get the window size of the active/focused application using java?

Tags: java, automation, printscreen

I have a program written in JAVA that creates a JPG file at a specified path whenever PRINTSCREEN is pressed. This program runs in background and uses the JIntellitype API.

My problem is that:

`screensize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());`

is the only available function I could find to get the screen size which I later use to get a buffered image like this:

`bf = screenRobot.createScreenCapture(screensize);`

where `bf` is a `BufferedImage` data type.

Is there any way that I could get the screensize of the window that is currently active so that unwanted content is not saved in the JPG file?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333187/how-to-check-current-window-size-in-java-swing

Answer (score 1):

```
Frame.getX()
Frame.getY()
Frame.getWidth()
Frame.getHeight()
```

Comment: I do not want the size of my application. I want the size of the window currently active. This could be a browser, notepad etc.

Comment: This might be more difficult. I don't think there is any standard Java library that does it. It may be necessary to call native OS code to do that.