# How to change the position of the object when the window size is changed?

Tags: java, object, position

As in the title. I would like objects moving on the board to change position propositionally to change the size of the window. How to do it?

Comment: This a bit on the broad side what are you using for your gui? What do you mean by position? can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you working with JFrames? How are your objects moving right now?

Comment: Sure. I am using Swing, i have class GameFrame extends JFrame and GamePanel extends JPanel. I have objects (img) which are falling from top. Every objects has random x position.

Comment: Questions should have the code you used, that is, you have tried so far. We typically don't ask others to write code for us, but help you understand why your current code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you are working with a `JFrame`.

You can get the dimensions of the `JFrame` as follows:

```
Dimension size = frame.getBounds().getSize()
double height = size.getHeight();
double width = size.getWidth();
```

Then you can make your object move by a percentage of those values.

Whenever the window's size changes, an event is triggered.
You can update the dimensions whenever that event is triggered with a `ComponentListener`.

```
class ResizeListener implements ComponentListener {

    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Dimension newSize = e.getComponent().getBounds().getSize();          
    }   
}
```

Do not forget to add the `ComponentListener` to your `JFrame`.

Sources: [How to check current window size in java swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333187/how-to-check-current-window-size-in-java-swing)

Comment: Ok thanks. Most of all i don't know how to make my object move by a percentage of those values. How to determine that percentage?

Comment: That depends on your preferences and implementation. Suppose your object has a velocityX property. Then you can for example set that velocityX to 0.02*width.

Comment: Ok, but in my implementation object has a random x position and the range is (0, frame_width). Is this an obstacle? So for example random position is x = 300, and after resize window it should has x = 340. I cannot figure out it how to do it.

Comment: make an updatePosition method that updates the position based on the width. And call that method in the componentResized method.

Comment: Yess i got it, but i have no idea how to update the position based on the width, that's the problem. Rest of all i understand.

Comment: If you don't already have it add a setter for the x position in your gameObject class. Then I suppose you have a list with all the objects. Loop through it and call the setter for each object like this ( setXPosition(width*percentage)); )

Comment: Ok, i got this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the componentResized method to recalculate the pieces' positions based on the actual frame size

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
      }
    };
    panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Resized to " + e.getComponent().getSize());
      }
      @Override
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Moved to " + e.getComponent().getLocation());
      }
    });
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("test", panel);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```